# Localhost cant start nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laragon

Hy!
I recently started learning laravel.I had to install laragon to use this framework, but i cant start nginx. I took a picture of the problem. I searched for every solution. But they didnt solve it. Can you tell me what i have to do to use nginx?
btw port 80 is allowed on this device. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzmN2.png)

Comment: can you share your nginx configuration as well?

Comment: It looks like a problem on your side. go to nginx/error.log file. There must a more detailed error there. If not best try to right_click>nginx>nginx.conf file and look there for any error.

Comment: thanks for the help,but i overlooked a thing which is that i downloaded the portable version. The installable version works fine. My bad for this :DDD

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.